# How to use && to combine multiple command lines into a single line and execute it in windows

Tags: command-line

I have a complex program,it needs to execute a serials of command,and I need to use && to combine them into a single one command,but it will make this command very long and thus very difficult to read and maintain.

Thus I tried to use set to combine them,the combined command can print correctly,but it can not execute correctly,below is a exmple of it,can anyone help me,please? Thanks in advance!

```
@echo off 
set command=dir
set command=%command% ^^^&^^^& tree

rem this line will print the combined string
echo %command%

rem this line will not execute the combined string
%command%

pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you are failing at.  Don't try to escape the `&&` and you will be fine.

An escaped `&&` is no longer a concatenation command.  The escapes are telling cmd.exe to treat them as text.  If you try to show this via an `echo` command, it will not work correctly as the `&&` will get a literal interpritation.

This is a simple batch file I just made ***AND IT WORKS PERFECTLY***.

```
@echo off
pushd %TEMP%
set TheCommand=tree
set TheCommand=%TheCommand% && dir

%TheCommand%

popd
```

***results (from a batch named "test.bat" sitting on desktop):***

```
C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop>test
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is XXXXXX

 Directory of C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp

03/09/2023  12:44 PM    <DIR>          .
03/09/2023  12:44 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/09/2023  12:31 PM         6,634,180 17e7aa4d-2647-47b0-b8ca-51ae8002695d.tmp
03/09/2023  12:29 PM                 0 189c12c6-9281-433a-94a4-2f2ebd4c7d5d.tmp
03/09/2023  12:44 PM                 0 2b1fb125-4350-4934-9e68-427321701000.tmp
03/09/2023  12:29 PM             5,763 38145745-fdf5-4cd2-ad17-d4277a2def23.tmp
03/09/2023  12:31 PM         2,923,294 66835aae-283d-433a-84bb-bf5da4aa777e.tmp
03/09/2023  12:31 PM           218,820 78abe627-e18a-4ec8-b920-e0c20eef117c.tmp
03/09/2023  12:31 PM           444,036 99121e46-5b7e-4985-9f6b-5e48f03963ad.tmp
03/09/2023  12:29 PM                 0 c7868484-5d58-48b0-a2b0-9dc22811c155.tmp
02/03/2023  07:58 AM    <DIR>          Diagnostics
03/09/2023  12:29 PM         4,194,332 ExchangePerflog_8484fa31fa76b577cfcccd43.dat
03/09/2023  12:30 PM        12,730,645 fcc5fb22-4ce2-48fc-9f66-2a8b31088e1d.tmp
03/09/2023  12:43 PM    <DIR>          Outlook Logging
03/09/2023  12:29 PM             1,205 VCXSrv.0.log
03/09/2023  12:43 PM                 0 {EB6CCD1B-254A-448B-B6D0-50D80EF04749} - OProcSessId.dat
              12 File(s)     27,152,275 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  741,288,493,056 bytes free
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is XXXXXX
C:.
├───Diagnostics
│   ├───EXCEL
│   ├───ONENOTE
│   │   └───Upload
│   ├───OUTLOOK
│   ├───POWERPNT
│   │   └───Upload
│   └───WINWORD
│       └───Upload
└───Outlook Logging

C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop>
```

Comment: Won't this execute `dir` before `tree` as `TheCommand` is set to `tree` twice?

Comment: @DuncG .. Yes, it will execute dir before tree but no, tree is not in there twice.  Think about it.  The first variable is getting clobbered by the inclusion of the first variable plus "&& dir".  Just run the batch and see.. it is harmless.

Comment: Setting command as `set TheCommand=echo hello && echo world` would print world before hello.

Comment: Yes it would but I don't understand what you are getting at @DuncG , OP said they couldn't concatenate strings and I showed them how and explained why.  I see no mention about the order of the commands.  Your solution was a clever workaround for a case where you have no choice but to have an escaped string.

Answer (score 0):

It is not ideal but you could execute the command in a new shell (`cmd /c`):

```
set command=dir
set command=%command% ^^^&^^^& tree

rem this line will print the combined string
echo %command%

rem execute the combined string
cmd /c %command%
```

Answer (score -1):

To execute a command built with string concatenation you need to use call

Like so

```
call %command%
```

If you want to read more details on call you can do so here
https://ss64.com/nt/call.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I just tested it and not work